# Rails 7 - PG "timestamp with time zone" attributes are Time instead of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In upgrading to Rails 7 from Rails 6, followed by `bundle exec rails app:update`, suddenly model attributes wrapping Postgres `timestamp with time zone` columns are returning as `Time` objects instead of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects.

Structure.sql example

```
CREATE TABLE public.blogs (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    #...
```

**before (Rails 6)**

```
Blog.last.created_at.class #=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

**after (Rails 7)**

```
Blog.last.created_at.class #=> Time
```

How can I get Rails to recognize that I want these columns to be wrapped with `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`?

Answer (score 2):

This has [been fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/75c406d774cbc4debf0d672a59a1e726b64cd57c) but [not yet released](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md).

To fix in the short term you'll need to explicitly tell Rails to parse this type of column with a time zone.

In an initializer, add `:timestamptz` as a `time_zone_aware_types` value.

```rb
# config/initializers/active_record.rb

ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_types << :timestamptz
```